How is this sentence divided exactly?

（変なことを言ってしまったな…）


　質問されたから答えたものの、明光の望む答えにも、自分の気持ちすら満足に表現できる言葉ではなかった、と思う。

I don't really understand how the sentence is divide in the second bubble. The narrator had something asked  (by 明光) and she replied, but I think she's saying her answer was not satisfactory?
"質問されたから答えたものの" I got something asked and even though I answer

明光の望む答えにも、自分の気持ちすら満足に表現できる言葉ではなかった、と思う。

How is にも used here? "The answer 明光 wanted?" "In the answer's 明光 wanted?"

This sentence seems simply broken. It's either that the author made a mistake, or you're misunderstanding something, like the order of the bubbles. If this is the author's mistake, perhaps they were going to say something like "明光の望む答えにも、自分の気持ちを満足に表現できる言葉にもなっていなかった" and messed it up.
